# Run Keyword If has invalid syntax

Tags: robotframework

Why is the following Robot statement complaining about 'Convert To Integer' keyword is invalid syntax?  Thanks

---

```
Run Keyword If    Convert To Integer    ${packets_2}    <=    Convert To Integer    ${packets_1}
...    FAIL    ${\n}[FAILED] Packets 2 not greater than packets 1.
...    ${\n}packets_time1: ${packets_1}  ${\n}packets_time2: ${packets_2}
```

Comment: What do you think `${\n}packets_time1: ${packets_1}  ${\n}packets_time2: ${packets_2}` is supposed to do? Are you wanting them to be an ELSE condition? Part of the `FAIL` keyword? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a keywords as the condition for `Run Keyword If`. The first argument is expected to be a python expression. Since you're trying to do a comparison of an integer, you can do that directly in the expression like so:

```
Run keyword if  int('${packets_2}') <= int('${packets_1})
...  FAIL  \n[FAILED] Packets 2 not greater than packets 1
```

The other problem is that you are supplying two other arguments: `${\n}packets_time1: ${packets_1}` and `${\n}packets_time2: ${packets_2}`. It's not clear what you think those are for. I'm guessing you want them as part of the error message. If that's the case, it will have to be all on one line or else robot will think they are extra arguments to the FAIL keyword.

```
Run keyword if  int('${packets_2}') <= int('${packets_1})
...  FAIL  \n[FAILED] Packets 2 not greater than packets 1\n$packets_time1: ${packets_1}\npackets_time2: ${packets_2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Yes, I want 2 args to be part of error message.